# convert php array into single JSON object

Tags: php, jquery, json

I converted a PHP array into JSON, using json_encode. I checked the console, and the objects are displaying in array, but as individual objects.

```
 [ { Object { 03-13-2012="Jazz"}, Object { 07-19-2012="Pop"}, ... ]
```

How can I convert this array into one object, like this (in PHP or jQuery):

```
Object { 03-13-2012="Jazz", 07-19-2012="Pop"}
```

Edit: Here's the beginning of my print_r for the PHP array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [03-13-2012] => Jazz
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [07-19-2012] => Pop
        )
)
```

Comment: What does your PHP array look like? (Use `print_r`.)

Comment: Simply merge each of the inner arrays in PHP or the objects in JS. Better yet, create the array in the correct format from the beginning!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Don't be afraid of **loops**

```
$output = array();
foreach($data as $v) {
    $output[key($v)] = current($v);
}
echo json_encode($output, 128);
```

[See Live Demo](https://eval.in/45005)

Comment: @Baba I am using return instead of echo because I need json response for mobile applications but return only returns last value of an array can you tell me how I can return whole array?

Answer (score 7):

In general, you need to prepare such a PHP array, which then should be [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and passed along to the server:

```
$data = array(

  '03-13-2012' => 'Jazz',
  '07-19-2012' => 'Pop',

);

echo json_encode( $data );
exit;
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to iterate over the indexed array making the keys of an associative array found therein into keys in a second associative array.

Assumption: You're starting with a JSON string, and you want to end up with a JSON string.

Warning: If you encounter duplicates you will overwrite.

Here's an example of what I'm talking about:

```
<?php
$foo = json_decode('[{"abc":"A123"},{"xyz":"B234"}]');
$bar = array();
foreach ($foo as $f) {
        foreach ($f as $k => $v) {
                $bar[$k] = $v;
        }
}

echo json_encode($foo)."\n";
echo json_encode($bar)."\n";
?>
```