# How to change a php array

Tags: php, laravel, query-builder

Simple question to which I don't have an answer.

How can I change my array from this:

```
[{"sku":"6"},{"buyers":"7"},{"base":"8"}]
```

to this:

```
[{"sku":"6","buyers":"7","base":"8"}]
```

I have three queries for three different database tables:

```
$sku = DB::table('mapiranje')->select(DB::raw('count(*) as sku'))
                                        ->where('mate_fk', '=', NULL)
                                        ->get();

        $kupac =    DB::table('mapkupci')->select(DB::raw('count(*) as buyers'))
                                        ->where('kupci_fk', '=', NULL)
                                        ->get();

        $base =     DB::table('dist_base')->select(DB::raw('count(*) as base'))
                                        ->where('base_fk', '=', NULL)
                                        ->get();
```

now each returns:

```
[{"sku":"6"}]
[{"buyers":"6"}]
[{"base":"6"}]
```

I have used merge_array to make a single array, but I get:

```
[{"sku":"6"},{"buyers":"7"},{"base":"8"}]
```

what I want is:

```
[{"sku":"6","buyers":"7", "base":"8"}]
```

Comment: This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems you have run into?

Comment: Also are you talking about changing actual strings or are these string representations of an array/object data structure?

Comment: possible duplicate of [convert php array into single JSON object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18432914/convert-php-array-into-single-json-object)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refactor your code according to right Laravel way:

```
$result = [
    'sku' => DB::table('mapiranje')->whereNull('mate_fk')->count(),
    'buyers' => DB::table('mapkupci')->whereNull('kupci_fk')->count(),
    'base' => DB::table('dist_base')->whereNull('base_fk')->count()
];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = [];
foreach($input as $oneInputRow) {
  $result[$oneInputRow[0]] = $oneInputRow[1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$target = array();
$start = array(array("sku"=>"6"), "buyers"=>"7"), "base"=>"8"));
foreach($start as $sub){
  foreach($sub as $key => $val){
    $target[$key] = $val;
  }
}
```

Not shure if laravel provides any special syntax, but just with php I'd do it as above.
Basicly you loop over the start-array. In that you loop over every array to get the key/val combination and put that into the target-array. 
For the second loop there would be other ways if you only have one entry in every secondary array.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code

```
$dd = '[{"sku":"6"},{"buyers":"7"},{"base":"8"}]';
$data = json_decode($dd,true);
$result = array();
foreach($data as $key=>$value){
        foreach($value as $key1=>$value1){
                $result[$key1] = $value1;
        }
}

echo json_encode($result); //this will print your required format result
```